What is the reading of a name that does not use the onyomi or kunyomi?
In some anime and manga, the names of characters have nothing to do with the onyomi or kunyomi of the kanji. How can they be read that way?
Eg: 虹(なな), 星空(なさ)

Presumably なさ is meant to be from NASA

I think so too.

Parents can give their children names with any Kanji from the jouyou and jinmeiyou sets, and give them any reading they want even if it's not am established one. 虹 as なな comes from the seven colours of the rainbow.
